# SystemVerilog: Interface variable referenced in task of another interface

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, vivado

Consider the following example code:

```
interface I();
    logic x;
    modport slave(input x);
endinterface

interface J(I.slave i);
    logic y;
    task process;
        if (i.x) begin
            // ...
        end
        if (y) begin
            // ...
        end
    endtask
endinterface

module test(input wire logic clock);
    I iXXX();
    J jXXX(.i(iXXX), .*);

    always @(posedge clock) begin
        jXXX.process();
    end
endmodule
```

This code works using Vivado 2017.1 Simulator and does *not* work using Vivado 2017.1 Synthesis which fails with the error

```
[Synth 8-146] cannot resolve hierarchical name ...
```

If you change the `if (i.x)` to `if (jXXX.i.x)`, it *does* synthesize. That seems completely odd to me. Maybe someone can shed light on whether this is expected behaviour and what the standard says about it.

Referencing `jXXX.i.x` would make sense if the task code is pasted into where the `process()` call occurs, with the special exception that non-interface variables like `y` (that are contained in the interface) have the name of the interface instance prepended. At the moment, I'd just vote for "compiler bug."
The workaround I am using at the moment is to add `wire logic HACK_i_x = i.x;` to the interface and reference this local wire like `if (HACK_i_x)` which simulates and synthesizes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a synthesis tool bug to me. Other simulators also handle the code you wrote. The hierarchical path `jXXX.` from inside `J` is an upward hierarchical reference to itself. Convoluted, but still legal.